# Linux host (Cpanel) - Cloudflare free SSL Certificate -> Connection is not secure -

Tags: linux, ssl

I have a website that is hosted in a Linux Server and I would like to solve a doubt about SSL certificate. Every time that a user access my website, part of this website is marked by browsers as "Connection not Secure".

Below I posted an image shows browser alert. In this case, this alert was showed on FireFox browser:

[image]

As you can see in image above, there is a browser message that said "This website contains content that is not secure (such as images).

My website use CloudFlare SSL free and i don't know why this is happen. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The key is "contains content that is not secure (such as images).

If your site includes javascript or fonts or images or, pretty much anything, from other sites with a "http" URL (as opposed to the "https") then the page is considered insecure.

Most commonly this may be images or advertising or analytic code.

So make sure that any resources you load are also loaded over https.